# Qt -- How to play audio files stored in QByteArray?

Tags: qt, qbytearray, qmediaplayer

I am working on a special application in Qt that stores its .mp3 audio files in a QSQLITE database as BLOB data.

**With the following code I create a QByteArray:**

```
QByteArray array = query->value(0).toByteArray();
```

**Then I try to play the sound with a QMediaPlayer:**

```
mediaPlayer.setMedia(   QMediaContent(   QUrl::fromEncoded(array)   )   );
mediaPlayer.play();
```

**But I unfortunately get this error:**

```
DirectShowPlayerService::doSetUrlSource: Unresolved error code 800c000d
```

The main thing that I would like to achieve is to be able to play these .mp3 files that are stored in the QByteArray.

Note: *Storing the pathway only in the database is not possible in that special circumstance.*

I would really-very appreciate your help.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Why are you using QUrl in here?

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide the `QByteArray` as a `QIODevice` to the `stream` parameter of `QMediaPlayer::setMedia(const QMediaContent & media, QIODevice * stream = 0)`.

Try the following:

```
QBuffer mediaStream(&array);
mediaPlayer.setMedia(QMediaContent(), &buffer);
mediaPlayer.play();
```

Comment: …and make sure both mediaStream and mediaPlayer survive the current function, as the playing is performed asynchronously.

Comment: It works on Windows and Linux but doesn't work on OSX, IOS and Android because the backend in these devices doesn't support stream playback.

Comment: the above code will not work becuse `QBuffer` needs to be open with `mediaStream.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);`